# How to use OR condition in t-field in qweb template in Odoo 9?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I am working on a report template in Odoo 9 qweb template and I need to use **OR** logical operator in t-field to get data from one of the two fields that I want to print their value in my report. Can I use **OR** here in t-field or I should use t-if with different span tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The t-field directive can only be used when performing field access (a.b) on a “smart” record (result of the browse method)

You need to use the conditional directive `t-if` as you said.

Comment: What about using `t-esc` instead of `t-field`? That should be a noteworthy possibility, too.

Comment: Yes, of course, and you will need to format values instead of automatic format based on the field type.